cyclotomic field extension and quadratic extension of Q
My book(Dummit and Foote, abstract algebra, p. 621 #33(b) and p. 637 #11(f)) says that for an odd prime $p$, $\mathbb{Q} (\zeta_p)$ contains either $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{p}) $ (if $~p \equiv 1 \rm ~mod ~4$ ) or $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-p}) $ (if $~p \equiv 3 \rm ~mod ~4 $). I want to prove this. ($\zeta_p = e^{2\pi i/p}$)
After searching about this, I could know that this is related to the Gaussian quadratic sum and the quadratic residue (and the Legendre symbol).
I found that for all $k$ which is quadratic residue modulo $p$, the summation $\sum_k \zeta_p ^k =:\beta $ can be represented in $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{p}) $ or $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{-p}) $.
(For example, if $p=7$, The numbers 1, 2, and 4 are quadratic residues modulo 7. So  $\beta=\sum_{k=1,~ 2, ~4} \zeta_7 ^k = \zeta_7+\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^4$.
Since $ \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^3+\zeta_7^4+\zeta_7^5+\zeta_7^6 =-1$, then $\zeta_7^3+\zeta_7^5+\zeta_7^6=-1-\beta$.
$\beta \times (-1-\beta) = \zeta_7^4+\zeta_7^6+\zeta_7^7+\zeta_7^5+\zeta_7^7+\zeta_7^8+\zeta_7^7+\zeta_7^9+\zeta_7^{10}=3+\zeta_7+\zeta_7^2+\zeta_7^3+\zeta_7^4+\zeta_7^5+\zeta_7^6=2$
Hence $-\beta-\beta^2 =2,~ \beta^2+\beta+2=0,~\beta=\dfrac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-7}}{2}$.
Take plus sign. Then $\sqrt {-7}=2\beta+1=1+2\zeta_7+2\zeta_7^2+2\zeta_7^4 \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$. )
I want to generalize this for any odd prime p. So I claim following.

For any odd prime $p$, let $\beta=\sum_{k=1}^{(p-1)/2} {\zeta_p}^{k^2}$. Then $~\beta+\beta^2 \in \mathbb{Z} $.

I tried to prove this claim, but I couldn't.
Is this true? If true, how can I prove this?
Thank you.

It suffices to show the following:
Let $0\neq x\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, then the number of solutions of $(a,b)$ to
$$ a+b=x$$
with $(\frac{a}{p})=1,(\frac{b}{p})=-1$ is a constant independent of $x$. (From here we can use the identity $\sum_{i=1}^p \xi_p^i=0$ to prove your claim.)
The above is indeed true, since for any solution of $a+b=1$, multiplying by $x$ yields
$$ ax+bx=x$$
where exactly one of $ax,bx$ is a quadratic residue. And vice versa. Hence the number of solutions to $a+b=x$ equals to the number of solutions to $a+b=1$.
Please tell me if you find any mistakes in my argument.

Thank you very much.
I have a question. What is the relationship between this field extensions and the representation of integers? Could you explain the connection in more detail?

Sorry, but what do you mean by 'representation of integers' :-)

I thought that letting x be the form "x=a+b" with (a/p)=1 and (b/p)=-1 is the representation of x. If my word choice was wrong, I'm sorry very much. Can you advise me a better word?

@commonlogarithm Well, I am not an expert in field theory, just a student taken several lessons, so I can't tell much. :) In fact I haven't seen a similar thing ($x=a+b$) before.

Thanks to your help!
